# Permission denied when using relx for building Cowboy Quick start project

Tags: file-permissions, cowboy, relx

I'm trying to `make` the Cowboy Quick start project, but I get `Permission denied` for `relx`. Even if I run it with `sudo make`. Any solution for this?

```
sudo make
Password:
 APP    cowlib.app.src
 APP    ranch.app.src
 APP    cowboy.app.src
 APP    hello_erlang.app.src
make: /Users/jonas/code/hello_erlang/relx: Permission denied
make: *** [rel] Error 1
```

Here is my file listing:

```
ls -al
total 1336
drwxr-xr-x  10 jonas  staff     340 Jan 17 17:35 .
drwxr-xr-x   7 jonas  staff     238 Jan 17 01:07 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 jonas  staff    1157 Jan 17 01:29 .erlang.mk.packages.v1
-rw-r--r--   1 jonas  staff      90 Jan 17 01:29 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x   5 jonas  staff     170 Jan 17 01:29 deps
drwxr-xr-x   6 jonas  staff     204 Jan 17 01:34 ebin
-rw-r--r--   1 jonas  staff    7495 Jan 17 01:26 erlang.mk
-rw-r--r--@  1 jonas  staff  661817 Jan 17 17:30 relx
-rw-r--r--   1 jonas  staff      79 Jan 17 01:37 relx.config
drwxr-xr-x   6 jonas  staff     204 Jan 17 01:34 src
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

relx is not executable.  Make it executable with

`chmod +x relx`

try again and report back :)